# data.table subsetting rows using a logical column: why do I have to explicitly compare with TRUE?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm wondering why for the given data.table:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- structure(list(number = 1:5, bmask = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE)), .Names = c("number", "bmask"), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

> DT
   number bmask
1:      1 FALSE
2:      2  TRUE
3:      3 FALSE
4:      4  TRUE
5:      5 FALSE
```

the expression `DT[bmask==T,.(out=number)]` works as expected:

```
   out
1:   2
2:   4
```

but `DT[bmask,.(out=number)]` causes error:

```
> DT[bmask,.(out=number)]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'bmask' not found
```

Is it a proper behavior of  the `data.table` package?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
DT[(bmask), .(out=number)]
#    out
# 1:   2
# 2:   4
```

---

The role of the parentheses is to put the symbol `bmask` inside of a function call, from whose evaluation environment the columns of the `DT` will be visible<sup>1</sup>. Any other function call that simply returns `bmask`'s value (e.g. `c(bmask)`, `I(bmask)`, or `bmask==TRUE`) or the indices of its true elements (e.g. `which(bmask)`) will work just as well but may take slightly longer to compute.

If `bmask` is **not** located inside a function call, it will be searched for in calling scope (here the global environment), which can also be handy at times. Here's the relevant explanation from `?data.table`:

> Advanced: When 'i' is a single variable name, it is not
>   considered an expression of column names and is instead
>   evaluated in calling scope.

---

<sup>1</sup>To see that `()` is itself a function call, type `` is(`(`) ``.